# Ablution when having nail polish?

Tags: wudu

Salam Alaykoum

Can a woman pray if she has nail polish on ? or does having nail polish prevent correct Ablution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a matter of ijtihad. Different scholars may have different opinions. According to some the `situation should be considered analogous to wiping of sock` and thus opined that

> So if nail polish has been put on after doing wudū, there is no need
>   to remove it; wudū can be done on it. However, if it has been put on
>   without doing wudū, then it must be removed and then wudū should be
>   done.

[Source](http://www.monthly-renaissance.com/issue/content.aspx?id=1440)

Answer (score -1):

Salam Allaikum, Of course u can. A nail polish is not an impurity. well, except u're sure it is.We already have all kinds of polish in the mosques, so the fine spots on your fingers shouldn't be an issue.when I said polish in the mosque I mean the wall paint, methal coats, doors name it.